# undefined method `activation_digest=' for #<User:0x007fe3810ceba0> Michael Hartl's book

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working through Michael Hartl's Rails book and I am about halfway through chapter 10-working on account activation.

I had everything working with the mailers but then when I tried to add a new user, I got the following error message: "undefined method `activation_digest=' for #"

I have been trying to follow along in the book the best that I can. I have my users_controller.rb here:

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
   before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]

   def new
     @user = User.new 
   end

   def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10) 
  end 

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end 

 def create 
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
    @user.send_activation_email
    flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    redirect_to root_url
   else
    render 'new'
   end 
  end 

 def update 
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
   else 
    render 'edit'
   end 
 end 

 def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
 end

 #confirms if a user is logged in
  def logged_in_user
   unless logged_in? 
   store_location
   flash[:danger] = "Please Log In."
   redirect_to login_url 
  end 
end 

private 

def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,       
 :password_confirmation)
end 

end
```

Here is my Model/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token
   before_save :downcase_email
   before_create :create_activation_digest

   before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
   validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
   VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
   validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, 
   format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
   has_secure_password
   validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
 def User.digest(string)
  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                              BCrypt::Engine.cost
  BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
 end

 #Returns a random token 
 def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
 end 

 #Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions
 def remember 
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
 end 

 #Returns true if the given token matches the digest
 def authenticated?(remember_token)
   return false if remember_digest.nil?
   BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
 end 

 #forgets a user
 def forget 
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
 end 

 private

  # Converts email to all lower-case.
  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
  def create_activation_digest
   self.activation_token  = User.new_token
   self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
  end
 end
```

The routes I have this:

```
  root 'static_pages#home'

  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

   get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'

  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'

  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'

  get 'signup' => 'users#new'

  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'

  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'

  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users 

  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
```

Please let me know if anything more is needed to be seen. I do have my App up on Github under the name sample_app, my username is ravenusmc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your project on Github, your `User` model doesn't have an `activation_token` or `activation_digest` column, nor does the model define them as attributes.

Your `User` model is trying to write to these columns in the `User#create_activation_digest` function which is most likely causing the issue.

You'll need to write a migration to add those columns to your User model or add them is attributes (ie `attr_accessor`) if they are not meant to be persisted.

Comment: Thank you! I found my error-you were right-I completely did not add the activation_digest and other two columns! Thank you again.